# Is it possible and necessary for an App to have zero memory leaks?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

There are some memory leaks found out when i "profile" my app with Instruments. 
Some of the leaks are obvious and easy to fix, but some are not. Some of the leak log showed in Instruments are really bothering me. For example:
[image]

I even can't tell which line of my code called these "strangers" behind the scene. How can   i fix these leaks? Is it a leak from my code? From the framework? Or just a false report?

Then my questions are:

A: Is it possible to fix all memory leak bugs? Some of them are really hard to deal with. And you even can't tell is it a bug from your code or from the frame work.

B: Is it necessary to fix all memory leaks? Couple of bytes leak might affect nothing. And the effort you put on to fix it may cost a lot more than you can get.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> A: Is it possible to fix all memory leak bugs? Some of them are really
>   hard to deal with. And you even can't tell is it a bug from your code
>   or from the frame work.

Yes it is possible, but please note some times the result you get from profiling dont pont you necessarily to a leak, sometimes they are objects that are not yet been auto released and sometimes they are not yours.

> B: Is it necessary to fix all memory leaks? Couple of bytes leak might
>   affect nothing. And the effort you put on to fix it may cost a lot
>   more than you can get.

If you mean for your application to not be rejected, then no thats not necessary, dont overwork and stress yourself on some bytes that you cant seem to find, dont go and search for a couple of bytes that has been lost here and there, start looking for leaks only when you notice that your application is really leaking.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's possible and yes you should.

Leaking ins't good in the long run, especially if you app runs in background. 
If the leak is in a third party library, tell the maker to fix it. Or if you have the code fix it your self. 
Leaking in you own code can easily be fixed, so do it.

Comment: Ideally, yes. But the tools aren't perfect. There's the usual false positive and false negative now and then... Then, there's the System's leaks every once in a while. I would say "Always do the best you can"

Comment: True, leaks in core frameworks aren't really fixable. but leaks in your own code should be avoided at all times.

Answer (score 0):

If your application is running for long times(consider as a some server) then it keeps on making that 2 bytes of leak at a frequent of time. At some point of time your heap will be full of infinite leaks. This may leads to malloc failure in your application. So fixing memory leak is more important for application which is running for long time. And also there will be possible to fix all the memory leaks.

If an application is running for short time means, once the application exist all the resources will be freed by the operating system, at that time leaked memory also will be freed.